# MySQL: select * from multiple tables where column1 or column2 = query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, search, multiple-tables

Let say I have a database with 4 tables:

- *pcs, laptops, tablets, smartphones*

Each of those tables contains the following columns:

- *id, brand, model*

How can I use a single query to display all results, from all of the tables based on the brand or model typed by the user? In psuedo-code, something like this:

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM   {all tables} 
 WHERE  {brand or model} LIKE %user_search%;
```

So that the user would be able to search any device by typing the brand or model. E.g. Typing *apple* would display all Apple smartphones and tablets. Typing a model number would display all devices with that model number, even from different brands.

Comment: This is a really bad table design, and the query would be much easier if it was normalised.  But you should look into `UNION`

Comment: @Siyual yes, I know it's bad design, it was just an example to understand how it works. In a real situation I would of course use a single table with the column "type" set to pc, laptop, tablet or smartphone. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, the best way is to run each query independently and use `union all`:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE brand LIKE '%user_search%' OR model LIKE '%user_search%'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE brand LIKE '%user_search%' OR model LIKE '%user_search%'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM t3 WHERE brand LIKE '%user_search%' OR model LIKE '%user_search%'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM t4 WHERE brand LIKE '%user_search%' OR model LIKE '%user_search%';
```

It is tempting to write this as:

```
select *
from ((select * from t1) union all
      (select * from t2) union all
      (select * from t3) union all
      (select * from t4) 
     ) t
where brand like '%user_search%' or model like '%user_search%';
```

However, this materializes the subquery, incurring extra overhead.

Also, if performance is an issue, you might want to consider full text indexes.

Comment: As an added comment, if any of those tables have fields in a different order, extra fields, or have incompatible data types between the unioned fields, you will encounter an error while using UNION ALL.

Answer (score 0):

let's try this
it will work .

```
SELECT * from (SELECT * FROM pcs as p 
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM laptops as l 
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM tablets as T ) as tt WHERE tt.brand or tt.model LIKE '%sams%'
```

it will also work .

```
SELECT * FROM pcs as p WHERE brand or model LIKE '%sams%'
UNION
SELECT * FROM laptops as l WHERE brand or model LIKE '%sams%'
UNION
SELECT * FROM tablets as t WHERE brand or model LIKE '%sams%'
UNION
SELECT * FROM smartphones as s WHERE brand or model LIKE '%sams%'
```